# return SPREADSHEET_ID after uploaded to google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I used a script to upload spreadsheet file to Google Drive using DocsList.createFile(), i wanted to automatically return via email the SPREADSHEET_ID for that newly uploaded file without technically opening the file first to manually determine the ID. How can I script this?

Thanks Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method getId() when creating the new file and putting it in a variable.

```
var new_doc_id = DocsList.createFile("Test","Some text.").getId();
Logger.log(new_doc_id);
```

After this just call MailApp to send the email.

```
MailApp.sendEmail("to@gmail.com", subject, "", {htmlBody : email_body, noReply : true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may return the ID of the newly created file in email.
Here is outline of the code.

```
//Your newly created file
  var file = DocsList.createFile(blob);
  var id = file.getId();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser(), 'Id of newly created spreadsheet', id);
```

Comment: Thanks... is there a way that uploaded excel file get converted to Google doc "sheet" type? so that when i applied the getID() will give the SPREADSHEET_ID key.

Comment: You can upload excel but can not be converted to Google spreadsheet but certainly you can upload data from CSV, Delimited text files etc which then can be populated in newly created blank spreadsheets using Apps Script.